# @RestController with ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, controller, spring-restcontroller

I am aware that `@RestController` is actually `@Controller` plus `@ResponseBody`. But if I change my method to return `ResponseEntity` as below, use of `@RestController` has no special task to perform here.

```
@GetMapping(value="/my-url")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getSomething( @RequestParam(value = "id") String id){
     //code here
}
```

So does that mean `@RestController` and `@Controller` perform same task if return type is `ResponseEntity` .

If that is the case why i see alot of examples still using `@RestController` along with `ResponseEntity` instead of simply using `@Controller`.  Am i missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point annotating your controller class with `@RestController` (instead of `@Controller`) if it only has handler methods that return `ResponseEntity`.

Spring MVC's default infrastructure registers a list of [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html) implementations for each different supported return type. For example, there's `ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler` for handler methods returning `ModelAndView` objects; there's `DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler` for methods returning `DeferredResult` or `ListenableFuture`; and there's `ViewNameMethodReturnValueHandler` for methods returning `String` values meant to be interpreted as view names.

The list is processed in order and the first handler found that can support the return value is used. The implementation handling `ResponseEntity`, [`HttpEntityMethodProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/HttpEntityMethodProcessor.html), is registered before the one handling `@ResponseBody`, [`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.html). The `@RestController` is, in a sense, ignored for the corresponding handler method returning `ResponseEntity`.

If you controller class has other handler methods that return values that are meant to be serialized directly, then it doesn't hurt to keep the `@RestController` (instead of annotating all those methods with `@ResponseBody`). But if all your methods return `ResponseEntity`, then it is unnecessary and potentially misleading.

FYI the default list of handlers is generated in a private method called `getDefaultReturnValueHandlers()` in [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html). You can provide your own list by calling [`setReturnValueHandlers`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html#setReturnValueHandlers-java.util.List-).

Comment: Link to spring documentation describing these would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user9735824 Added some docs, the order seems to be an implementation detail that might change in the future. I couldn't find documentation about it. I consulted the source code.